# Swift 2 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, nsexception

I am getting an NSException error which I cannot understand since using the updated swift 2. I am aware that the exception is common and in itself doesn't really help. I have included the code I am using. The code is from the start of a calculator application. While this code runs perfectly fine in swift it now offers the exception in the updated swift 2.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var mainDisplay: UILabel!

@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle
    print("digit = \(digit)")
}}
```

The error is connected to the line `print("digit = \(digit)")`as far as I can tell. In swift 2 println was removed and combined into print but I am not sure why calling in digit is causing an exception? I am completely new to swift and so any help would be appreciated to help me understand the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Could you send us a print of the NSException error you are receiving?

Comment: 2015-11-02 15:04:20.868 Calculator[7542:2075339] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Calculator.ViewController 0x7f8091f24760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key maindisplay.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the `appendDigit:` method. You should check your Storyboard or XIB as there is a connection problem with your `IBOutlet`, which came probably after your renaming the variable from `maindisplay` to `mainDisplay`.

ADDITION:

The solution is to look inside the Storyboard or XIB at the linked `UILabel`, remove the outlet connection, and set it again using the newly renamed `mainDisplay IBOutlet var`.

Comment: Perfect I can see exactly what I did now, I did create a new outlet connection but failed to remove the old one which is what caused the issue. Deleting that old one so only the newer one remained fixed it. Thank you very much